# image not showing in ejs template, nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

i use ejs template with node.js for printing invoice, my code like this 
**ejs file**

```
<img style="margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px; margin-top:5px;" src="logo.png" height="100" alt="">
```

**server.js**

```
app.use('public', express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
```

**directory** 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

While you are working with ejs and node. You should have to put whole path of img in scr=""

For eg : /home/Chirag/project/project-name/assets/IMG/logo.png

Comment: what about in production ?

Comment: idk much but you can try this, 
<img src="http://www.example.com/assets/img/logo.png" />
which is works for me.